# In App Voices (iOS)

Tags: ios

If I had a list of names in an app and I wanted people to pronounce their names correctly. How would I go about enabling a user to select the name and then a voice relay how it's properly said through the iPhone. (For example siri voice pronouncing "Fred Flintstone" back to the user so they know how to say it the right way)

Comment: You can't _teach_ Siri how to pronounce.

Comment: @matt it's funny that you say that, because you can. Off topic, but, when Siri pronounces a name wrong, say "This is not how you pronounce X", repeating it the way she said it (ie the wrong way). She will ask you to pronounce it for her and then she will give you a list with options. It's how I taught her how to pronounce my girlfriends name, works great.

Comment: Okay, I meant you can't teach Siri _in code_. So for the OP's actual use case, if the built-in voice doesn't say "Fred Flintstone" the way you want, you're kind of stuffed.

Comment: The o.p.'s question seems a little too broad to answer properly.  Do you want some service (siri) or built in library to pronounce the name?  or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the AVSpeechSynthesizer class, documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/

Answer (score 0):

To make Siri speak "Fred Flinstone", you would do this:

```
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@"Fred Flintstone"];
AVSpeechSynthesizer *speechSynthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
[speechSynthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

Pretty simple and powerful!

You can also adjust how Siri sounds by adjusting the properties that AVSpeechUtterance has (note that the value needs to be between 0 - 1.0):

```
 utterance.rate = 0.085;
 utterance.pitchMultiplier = 0.85;
 utterance.volume = 0.8;
```

Hope this helps.  If you want a little more detail, I wrote a blog post on it last week: https://medium.com/@alanscarpa/how-to-use-avspeechsynthesizer-to-make-your-app-talk-d07f424689b0